# Substitution of one symbolic variable for two symbolic variables

Tags: matlab, substitution, symbolic-math

I have a question about MATLAB symbolic variable substitution which I feel should have an elegant solution but I can't work out the method of how.

I want to substitute one symbolic variable for two symbolic variable in an equation. I have taken the differentiation of a position with respect to time to find the velocity, and then taken the differentiation of the velocity to find the acceleration. Now, I want to substitute something like `vel=acc*t` into the equation for velocity so as to eliminate the symbolic variable t.

For example

```
vel_robot=S*acc*t;
```

and I want it to show;

```
vel_robot=S*vel
```

This is a simplified problem of the program I am working on. Basically I need to eliminate t from my answer.

Is there a way to do this in MATLAB? I know I can substitute one symbolic variable with another using `vel_robot = subs(vel_robot,acc,vel)` but what I want to know is if I can substitute two symbolic variables with another e.g. `vel_robot = subs(vel_robot,acc*t,vel)` - N.B. Subs doesn't work in this case.

Thank you!

Comment: It is not exactly safe and you need to worry about order and spacing. But you could give `control+H` a chance. Or if your answer is simple enough perhaps dividing by `acc*t` can do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately the program needs to be more generic so I can't use control+H...though it is how it is currently solved :)

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is with assumptions and simplification using [`assume`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assume.html) and [`simplify`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html):

```
syms S acc t vel
vel_robot=S*acc*t;
assume(vel == acc*t);
vel_robot = simplify(vel_robot)
```

which returns

```
vel_robot =

S*vel
```

Note that `vel` had to be declared as a symbolic variable here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I don't have the command assume with my Matlab version (2011a) but it is great that there is that capability in more recent versions